# ScrollPane setVvalue() is not working in Javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, scrollpane

I have tried the following code to create dynamic TextField and added it in VBox which is within ScrollPane. But the problem that I am facing is that, if more number of TextField is added than the TextField is not visible in ScrollPane.

The line scrollPane.setVvalue(Double.MAX_VALUE); is not working.

ScrollPaneDemo.java

```
package scrollpanedemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author vikassingh
 */
public class ScrollPaneDemo extends Application {

    VBox vboxInner = new VBox();
    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    List<TextFieldClass> textfieldClass = new ArrayList<TextFieldClass>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        VBox.setVgrow(vboxInner, Priority.ALWAYS);
        vboxInner.setPrefHeight(200);
        vboxInner.getChildren().clear();
        textfieldClass.clear();
        newRow();
        scrollPane.setContent(vboxInner);

        Scene scene = new Scene(scrollPane, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void newRow() {
        // Add row
        textfieldClass.add(new TextFieldClass(new TextField()));
        TextField newTextFileld = null;
        HBox productDHbox = null;
        for (TextFieldClass ctObject : textfieldClass) {
            newTextFileld = ctObject.getTextField();
        }

        vboxInner.getChildren().add(newTextFileld);
        // Rate TextField Listner
        newTextFileld.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
            if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER) || event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.TAB) || event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.RIGHT)) {
                // Add new TextField
                newRow();

                // 
                //**** Ensure Visibility of last TextField (Not working)

                scrollPane.setVvalue(Double.MAX_VALUE);

                //***** Ensure Visibility of last TextField (Not working)
                //

                textfieldClass.get(textfieldClass.size() - 1).getTextField().requestFocus();
                event.consume();
            }

        });
    }

}
```

TextFieldClass.java

```
package scrollpanedemo;

import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

/**
 *
 * @author vikassingh
 */
class TextFieldClass {

    private final TextField newTextFiled;

    TextFieldClass(TextField newTextFiled) {

        this.newTextFiled = newTextFiled;
    }

      // First textfield
    public TextField getTextField() {
        return newTextFiled;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just move your setVvalue() statement after if condition block. It did not solve your problem completely, but when user will type something, the last text field will be visible automatically.

```
    newTextFileld.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event ->
    {
        if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER) || event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.TAB)
                || event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.RIGHT))
        {
            // Add new TextField
            newRow();

            textfieldClass.get(textfieldClass.size() - 1).getTextField().requestFocus();
            event.consume();
        }
        scrollPane.setVvalue(Double.MAX_VALUE);

    });
```